# How do I get my current wordpress theme's header & footer in a PHP file?

Tags: php, wordpress, header, footer

The file is manually created by me & not a part of the theme.

I've tried by placing `get_header( )` inside my file but it shows a error that `get_header( )` is not defined.

Comment: How are you loading this file? What are you trying to accomplish exactly? I think you just uploaded a file to Wordpress, and access it directly. This is not a preferred method, your file will run completely outside Wordpress. Try to use for example the WP template system. Then `get_header()` & `get_footer()` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have default header and footer names. Then you need to set additional name.

> Includes the header.php template file from your current theme's directory. If a name is specified then a specialised header header-{name}.php will be included.
>
> If the theme contains no header.php file then the header from the
>   default theme wp-includes/theme-compat/header.php will be included.

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/get_header

Answer (score 0):

I highly discourage it but you need to include the wp-load.php file that resides in the root of your wordpress installation, in your lone php file. That is how you have access to WP functions and capabilities.

But again **I HIGHLY DISCOURAGE IT**. Find another way, create a simple plugin and activate it, in which you put that php file's code, or if part of a theme, just create a new page template with a different header, that you can call with `get_header('name_of_header_without_php_extension')` or a new footer called the same way but with `get_footer()`.

There are alternatives, maybe if you share what you are trying to achieve, we can guide you to a better, safe solution.

Answer (score -1):

Based on theme it's defer.

Same time define as get_header(),get_footer()

But now latest themse assign particular theme name based header & footer function

Ex: Theme Name is "Demo"

So the header function assign as  Demo_get_header() or get_header_Demo()

Comment: Sorry, but you CANNOT use `get_header()` like that, please read [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header).

Answer (score -2):

Dashboard ->Appearance ->Editor -> in your Template file or in page.php write

```
<?php get_header()?>,<?php get_footer()?>
```

if you want to use different headers on different pages 
1. create new file , name it header-example.php
2. you can call this header in any page using code

Comment: Please do not encourage users this PHP editing method. When you edit PHP ALWAYS use something like FTP and a code editor. You do have a point about the Template file, see my comment also.